# File provider Uri errors

Tags: java, android

I have provided the correct `Uri` path for the image file in `File Provider`. But while executing the android app in Android  Studio, I am facing errors in the `Uri` parse(path) of the Main Activity java file.

Error in Main Activity:

```
            Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.dragosholban.androidfacedetection", photoFile);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR IN LOGCAT:

```
at com.dragosholban.MainActivity.onImageFromCameraClick(MainActivity.java:52)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the **complete** stack trace.

Comment: Remove the `FileProvider`. It is not needed. Also, post your logcat.